# Bash Script to grep string in file and output to another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script to grep for a string and succeeding few lines and then output to another file.

Here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$#"

if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then

        echo "Usage : ./redirectTrace.sh searchText inputFile number_of_Lines_succeeding_the_searchText outputFile"

else

        searchText=$0
        inputFile=$1
        lines=$2
        outputFile=$3

        echo "$0 , $2, $3, $4"

        grep -i -A "$lines" "$searchText" $inputFile > $outputFile
fi
```

When I execute this as `./redirectTrace.sh Drag:: log/Test.log 10 Drag1.log` , I get

```
grep: log/Test.log: invalid context length argument
```

If I don't pass number of lines and execute with a fixed value, I get another error.

Script :

```
grep -i -A 10 "$searchText" $inputFile > $outputFile
```

Execution : 
./redirectTrace.sh Drag:: log/Test.log Drag1.log`

I get following error :

```
grep: Drag::: No such file or directory
```

Also `log/Test.log` file becomes empty.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major part is because `$0` is the name of the *script* not the first argument to the script. The first argument is `$1`, the fourth argument is `$4`, etc.

So your assignments should be:

```
searchText=$1
inputFile=$2
lines=$3
outputFile=$4
```